# Substituir strings por elementos de uma lista

Tags: python, pandas

```
# Código
list = [a for a in range(100,103)]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":['x','y','z'],
    "B":[0,1,2],
    "C":[0,0,0]
})
```

Preciso substituir as strings da coluna `C` pelas strings do `list`, de modo que a primeira string do `list` substitua a primeira string da coluna `C`, a segunda string do `list` substitua a segunda string da coluna `C`.

Tentei aplicar um `replace`, mas na substituição é retornado todas as strings do `list` dentro de cada string da coluna `C`, ficando desta maneira:

```
0    [100, 101, 102]
1    [100, 101, 102]
2    [100, 101, 102]
```

O resultado que desejo, seria isto:

```
    A   B   C
0   x   0   100
1   y   1   101
2   z   2   102
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apenas substitua a coluna no *Dataframe*.
Evite usar os identificadores dos [builtins](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html) de linguagem como nomes de variáveis.

Exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd 

l = list(range(100,103))


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":['x','y','z'],
    "B":[0,1,2],
    "C":[0,0,0]
})

df["C"] = l

print(df)
```

Resultado:

```
   A  B    C
0  x  0  100
1  y  1  101
2  z  2  102
```

Ou use [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) para acessar um grupo de linhas e colunas por um rótulo.

```
import pandas as pd 

l = list(range(100,103))


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":['x','y','z'],
    "B":[0,1,2],
    "C":[0,0,0]
})

df.loc[:, "C"] = l

print(df)
```

Resultado:

```
   A  B    C
0  x  0  100
1  y  1  101
2  z  2  102
```

<sup>Veja os exemplos no [COLAB](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13f_SBHb15IjkYbTO3wcHxvEfhO1H-BsJ?usp=sharing)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado, simples e rápido